# How can I create a time counter by aggregating a view?

Tags: views

I need to create a time counter that will take a users input of time in hours and minutes, add them and then display the cumulative results?

I am not sure how to accomplish this. It has been suggested to create a content type with a time field and then aggregate the results.

Any advice/direction will be appreciated.

Comment: can you tell us more about the specific task or problem you're trying to do?  what is the site's function? WHY are they entering time?

Comment: users will 'pledge' a certain amount of time from 1 to 60 minutes. then I could create a view to aggregate the cumulative results pledged from different users and display the results.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a total hack with Drupal

I would use the View type of "Table",  then create a views-view-table--VIEWNAME.tpl.php

You'll see that it's set in to a real easy to read loop through the rows.   Modify the HTML structure to suit your needs,  but also add in a simple $var++; and then place that at the end of your rows.